# Error when importing Maven project to Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, clojure

I'm trying to import a maven project using the m2eclipse import wizard and I keep running into problems. The latest is a build error message that reads 'No marketplace entries found to handle clojure-maven-plugin:1.3.10:compile in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.' I have tried switching the maven installation from embedded to /usr/share/maven2 to no avail. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

EDIT: The problem was that I was compiling with an incompatible version of java

Comment: Just import it like existing project and enable maven nature later.

Comment: @AleksandrM this is what I've been doing, I want to build the project with eclipse

Comment: `File` -> `Import` -> `Existing Projects into Workspace`.

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Which m2e version have you installed in Eclipse? Have you imported the project via `Project -> Import -> Existing Maven Project`?

Answer (score 1):

As a work around you could try to use the command mvn eclipse:eclipse in your maven project folder (terminal) providing that maven is installed on your ubuntu distribution to convert your maven project to a eclipse project.

If not you can install maven through apt-get update install maven

Maybe that helps

Comment: I've already tried that and maven is already installed, it gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid to say, but you very probably can not get this to run in Eclipse. There is no native support for Maven in Eclipse and because of that every little thing needs a translator Eclipse plugin that will translate a Maven model into an Eclipse-digestible one. If you happen to use some Maven plugins that have no translator plugins available for Eclipse, you're doomed. And your Clojure plugin sounds like a prime candidate for this situation. Now, take what I have said here with a grain of salt as I never used this specific plugin before with Eclipse, but I did run into the exact same issue with different plugins.